# Magnific popup Dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I seem to be having an issue where using Magnific and then telling it to programmatically go to the provided index breaks, but only when moving to the zeroth element then back.

I've created a codepen here - [codepen](http://codepen.io/L337LUKE/pen/xGawbZ)

This is the code that appears to be the problem especially with the goTo() method.

```
if (this.items[i].slug === elSlug)
{
    this.goTo(i);
}
else
{
    // should log every other index other than the one we're looking for
    console.log(i);
}
```

I also noticed that magnific seems to convert the array/objects provided into an items object with more properties and the provided under a data object.

Has anyone had this kind of issue or know of a way around this?

[edit]

It seems to be something to do with the fact that because of how magnific converts the data (after) opening the modal, it needs to be accessed differently, I've tried changing some conditionals but still no joy =/

Comment: Mmm, strange if you don't do strict comparison here `if (this.items[i].slug === elSlug)` it will at least log all the other indexes like you have mentioned in your comment block.

Answer (score 0):

Your `elSlug` variable and the `slug` property are not consistent. For Example, for Sea Salt & Vinegar, `elSlug` is set to `sea-salt-vinegar` but its comparing it against `sea-salt-&-vinegar`, so its not matching properly.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, I had updated this but forgot to paste into the pen, updated, bust still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem, with a little help from a friend!

Turns out magnific changes the `items[]` array when you initialise the modal.

So we don't just have an array of pure data objects we instead have an object with extra data pushed into it as well as Magnfic placing our supplied data under a **data** object.

This check got me where I needed to go, hope it helps someone else in the future!

```
for (i ; i < len ; i++) {
    if (this.items[i].slug === elSlug || (this.items[i].data && this.items[i].data.slug === elSlug))
    {
        this.goTo(i);
        break;
    } else{
        // some kind of problem, do other stuff
    }
}
```